# node-schedule on Heroku (not Scheduler add-on from Heroku)

Tags: node.js, heroku, cron

I would like to have some emails executed on a certain date at a certain time as a one off execution. `node-scheduler` looks like the one for the job and I was just wondering if there is going to be any problem with using this on the Heroku servers in terms of it restarting once a day and whether or not this will disrupt whatever the `node-scheduler` uses to do its thang?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only two issues you may need to consider:

1. What happens if the server restarts right at the time it's scheduled to execute? This is unlikely but it's still possible. If this is a critical concern I'd probably set a `time_of_last_run` value on the job in the database. Then upon start, if the last run time is before the last expected time, you probably missed executing it.
2. When the 'next' server comes back up you'll need to re-schedule the job. That means you'll need to store these jobs in some sort of database.

Other than those, shouldn't have a problem.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'd considered the first and since this is just the beginning of the site I'm willing to let it go for now. Number 2 though, If i do store them in a database (which I already do for just record keeping) how would I do this exactly? Would I just store all the dates and then when the server restarts loop through each one and filter them through the job? My plan was just to have the job be scheduled/set in a `router.get('myWhatever'`. would this not be the best way?

Comment: On server start, grab all the scheduled jobs from the database. Loop through each one and pass the date to `node-scheduler`. This is to make sure any previously scheduled job still happens. If you're using `router.get('...'` to create new scheduled jobs, simply save the job to the database and then call `node-scheduler` with the date. If the server restarts before that time, it'll pull the jobs in from the database and execute them when the time comes.

Comment: is there any documentation or article on how to deal with the heroku restarting its servers? I can't find anything